# Sensitising intermittent parallel build issue (cmake)

Tags: makefile, cmake, intermittent

I am trying to debug an intermittent parallel build issue in my cmake build system around some generated files. It is however difficult to reliably test or reproduce the issue.

Does anyone know any way to exacerbate or sensitise such issues? Or other strategies for debugging them?

Comment: The code isn't public I'm afraid but used the more eyes suggestion here and it did help uncover the issue. If you add that as an answer then I'd vote for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely a missing add_dependencies to force one target to build completely before another begins, or an add_custom_command output that is used in more than one library.

If both libraries start building at the same time, and they both trigger running the custom command at the same time, then you'll get two competing custom commands running, and they may overwrite each other's results, or intermingle results.

Is your code public? Can you post it for others to inspect?

One good strategy is simply exposing it to other developers for "more eyes"...